# IntelliJ forcing me to restart my app on every code change

Tags: macos, grails, intellij-idea

I am on Grails 1.3.5 and IntelliJ 9.0.4 on a Mac with the latest JDK

I have the simplest of Grails projects: a helloworld that simply renders a string directly from a controller. I created it through the New Project wizard in IntelliJ. That went fine and IntelliJ picks up the correct grails SDK.

The problem is that IntelliJ makes me restart the app to see any changes I make to my code, (e.g. changing the "hello world" string.

If I edit the same controller with a text editor (eg TextMate) and run the app from the command line with `grails run-app` I *do* get hot code replacement, which is obviously what I want...

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points:

- I strongly recommend using the latest IntelliJ X EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+EAP) since Grails support has been improved a lot since 9.0.x
- If your IntelliJ config files got messed up, you can easily recreate them with 'grails integrate-with --intellij'. N.B. this recreates the config files in and old format and IntelliJ suggest to upgrade them - follow this procedure
- Make sure your run configuration has uses at least the same memory settings than Grails uses when run from the command line, I'm fine with setting the 'VM parameters' field to '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1G'
- If build problems occur (in rare cases the IntelliJ's internal compiler is more strict than plain Groovy), disable the 'Make' checkbox in the run config dialog.

If the problem persists, paste a screenshot of the run configuration you're using.